# why doesnt webappcreator run?

Tags: gwt

I'm just running thru the instructions here on windows:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted

```
$ ./webAppCreator -out MyWebApp com.mycompany.mywebapp.MyWebApp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/tools/WebAppCreator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.google.gwt.user.tools.WebAppCreator.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Are you by any chance running webAppCreator through a symlink ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the folder where webAppCreator is to your PATH variable so you can run without needing to be in that folder ... Also you prob dont use Cygwin, but don't use cygwin command line and use the regular Windows command line (I had same error when using Cygwin)